# 5GHz network hidden from my PC

Tags: wireless-networking

Currently I am running Win7 on my desktop with Linksys AE6000 USB WiFi Adapter and I have my router ASUS RT-AC58U broadcasting in both 2.4GHz and 5GHz.

The problem I am having is, my phone can "see" the 5GHz network all the time, but my PC is having intermittent issues on 5GHz. Sometimes it can see and connect to it, but sometimes it only sees the 2.4GHz. I need to be on 5GHz cause somehow my WiFi kept dropping in 2.4GHz. Is this issue common or how can I improve the situation?

P/S: They are located in less than 10 meters away.

Comment: If both frequencies are unstable, you should verify that the adapter is working properly in other locations, and if it is, look for sources of interference.  Note that 10 meters is not a short distance for wifi, depending on the environment.

Comment: That adapter is *very* small. Please try with a USB extension cable to get away from the PC’s interference zone.

Comment: 5G is stable, and the adapter is working fine. The only interference I could think of is wireless keyboard/mouse but I have no choice as I need them.

its about 5 metres separated by a thin wall.

@Daniel B Yes, the adapter is really small, you think the interference is inside the PC casing ?

Comment: Your statement *somehow my WiFi kept dropping in 2.4GHz* makes me wonder if there's something wrong with your router.

Answer (score 0):

First Check the environment for noisy device near there, mikrowave, The metal and steel can cause the problem. 
You may also want to check about Chanel Frequency interference and analyze wifi signal infotmation of ther SSID in environment, However this is no such problematic as the same as 2.4 G Network.

Check about the firmware and latest update too. Many of problem will be fixed during latest release and by update.

You should also note that the 5 G frequency is highly depend on straight sight access, in-spite of 2.4 G. and this is why this is not very common for indoor place with wall, door and something else in middle of access.

Due to my experience, Considering about the glass is also very important. because it can reflect your signal in middle of road and prevent direct access to AP. I hope these are good advice. Please Mark it if you find it useful :)

Comment: The only thing I can think of that is causing interference is my wireless keyboard/mouse combo.

Firmwares and drivers are both latest, router and adapter are separated by ~10metres with a thin wall, no glass is between them.

Comment: Good, but Bluetooth usually use 2.4 G frequency to communicate with devices. so this is not considered interference cause at this way. you can try with disabling 2.4 G Network completely, and/or changing channel too to check the new result.